# JavaFx 2.0: get TreeItems or Nodes currently visible on screen

Tags: treeview, javafx, javafx-2

I have `TreeView<TitledPane>` and want to show only "unread" content of `TitledPane`.

I would like to have some event to be notified if content of `TitledPane` is visible on screen.

`TitledPane` has `expandedProperty()`, so collapsed, but i do not see anything to filter out TreeItems that are far away on TreeView and not displayed.

Another potential way i thought about is to check visibility of node sitting in TitledPane using `visibleProperty`, but that seems to not work.

`pane.visibleProperty().addListener(new EnhancedListener(pane));`

```
private class EnhancedListener implements ChangeListener<Boolean>
{
    Node parent;
    EnhancedListener(Node parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, 
                        Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) {
        TitledPane p = (TitledPane) parent;
        System.out.println(((Label)p.getContent()).getText()+" " + arg2);
    } 
}
```

I use JavaFX 2.0.3

Answer (score 4):

See this JavaFX forum thread ["ListView Visible Items"](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2335633/listview-visible-items) and the related JavaFX issue database entry ["Item visibility in scrollable components should be in API"](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090386) for a request for enhancement to make this easier to achieve what you seek.

The `visibleProperty` is to do with whether it is possible for an item to be seen when added to a scene, not whether it is currently being displayed (e.g. if a clip or scroll of the layout node currently prevents a child node from being displayed, the child node can still have a visibleProperty value of true, even though you can't currently see it).  So in short, as you discovered, it won't help you here.

The above linked forum thread provides the following workaround for `ListView`, which you may be able to adapt to your `TreeView` situation, though you would need to work out some way to know that the TreeView's rendered cells displayed on the scene are changing to trigger the "event" you require.

```
VirtualFlow vf = ((VirtualFlow)((ListViewSkin)myList.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0)).getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0));
System.out.println(vf.getFirstVisibleCell().getIndex()+", "+vf.getLastVisibleCell().getIndex());
```

Comment: I've just updated the links which were broken. Could you please just check out whether I've re-linked them to the correct pages...

Comment: @PrimosK Yes, perfect.  Thanks for that PrimosK.  Nice work tracking down the links, especially the Oracle forum one.  I thought Oracle had shut down the forum and the data was gone, I didn't realize they had transferred the old forum data into a new forum system.  It is a shame they couldn't run an automatic redirect from the old threads to the new system.  For the JavaFX bug system, they used to do a redirect from the old JavaFX bug tracker to the new OpenJDK one, but they stopped doing it, so the old links stopped working, so thanks for fixing the bug link as well.